# how to keep validation off if some section of forms not showing during form-filling in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

how to keep validation off if some section of forms not showing during form-filling in jquery. as

```js
function formsubmit(){
 var ammount = $('#ammount').val();
 var emp_status = $("input[name='empstatus']:checked").val()?$("input[name='empstatus']:checked").val():'undefined';
 var com_name = $('#com_name').val();
 var ann_inc=$('#ann_inc').val();
 var city=$('#city').val();
 var emi_paid =  $("input[name='emi_paid']:checked").val()?$("input[name='emi_paid']:checked").val():'undefined';

 flag = true;
 if (ammount.trim()=='') {
  $('#msgammount').css('color','red');
     $('#msgammount').text('Please Enter Price');
     $('#msgammount').show();
  return false;
 }
 if (emp_status == 'undefined') {
  $('#msgempstatus').css('color','red');
  $('#msgempstatus').text('Please Enter Price');
  $('#msgempstatus').show();
  return false;
 }
 if (emi_paid == 'undefined') {
  alert('undefined');
  return false;
 }
}
```

I want to hide the error emi_paid section as some of the user not going to fill emi_details if they will not took any loan from bank, so i am using radio button if user has any existing loan then only emi option appear,

my code run well the only thing disappoint me to hide the emi_paid error, it will show always at the time of form submission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use validation js Like [validate.js](https://github.com/rickharrison/validate.js/) or [jQuery.validationEngine v2.6.2](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine).These validation are easy to use as well as these validation has a setting to turn on or off validation for hidden element according to your requirement.

Hidden validation for hidden elements in form submit

```
    $.validator.setDefaults({
    ignore: ":hidden"
     });
```

I highly recommend your to use these.